# Android: Unable to specify List<String> return type for AsyncTask:doInBackground

Tags: android, list, android-asynctask

I have the following block of code based on an asynctask.
I'm trying to return a List variable via return LoadFeed()
and the return type of doInBackground is String.
If I change the return type of doInBackground from String to List
then I get an error

```
"The return type is incompatible with AsyncTask<String,Void,String>.doInBackground(String[])"
```

How do I fix this error?
Please help

Thanks,

```
  private class DispData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
   private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MessageList.this);
   // can use UI thread here
   protected void onPreExecute() {
      dialog.setMessage("Fetching scores...");
      dialog.show();
   }


   // automatically done on worker thread (separate from UI thread)
   protected String doInBackground(final String... args) {
      return loadFeed();

   }


  // can use UI thread here
   protected void onPostExecute(final List<String> result) {
      if (dialog.isShowing()) {
         dialog.dismiss();
      }
     adapter = 
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(MessageList.this,R.layout.row,result);
     MessageList.this.setListAdapter(adapter);

   }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Change your class definition to:

```
class DispData extends AsyncTask<String, Object, List<String>>
```

This will force the doInBackground declaration to become:

```
protected List<String> doInBackground(String... arg);
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you really should add `@Override` annotations to your `onPreExecute()`, `doInBackground()`, and `onPostExecute()` methods. On an `AsyncTask`, this is critical to help you keep track of all the data types.

Then, if you want `doInBackground()` to return `List<String>`, you need to change it both in `doInBackground()` and in your `AsyncTask` declaration (the third data type will need to change from `String` to `List<String>`), to go along with your change that you already made to `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: Added the @overrides. Changed retun data type in both places. Still getting 'Force Close' error. What is the significance of the of the 3 parameters in the AsyncTask declaration? Guess I need to know this before I can debug furthur. TIA.

Comment: Sorry. It works! There is some problem with my LoadFeed procedure. Will debug that. :-)

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly! :-)